# How to get multiple lines of stdin Swift HackerRank?

Tags: swift

I just tried out a HackerRank challenge, and if a question gives you x lines of input, putting x lines of let someVariable = readLine() simply doesn't cut it, because there are lot's of test cases that shoot way more input to the code we write, so hard coded readLine() for each line of input won't fly.

Is there some way to get multiple lines of input into one variable?

Comment: One might consider this to be a part of the challenge (reading multiple lines into single variable, that is).

Comment: Perhaps call readLine() in a *loop*? The number is test cases is usually known.

Comment: @AntonBronnikov, I kind of consider writing smart code that solves the question as the actual challenge. Up until now I had been hardcoding the input until I saw that the code gets run through different test cases after you submit it. Haha. I had more trouble trying to figure out how to get the bloody input hahah.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For anyone else out there who's trying a HackerRank challenge for the first time, you might need to know a couple of things that you may have never come across. I only recently learned about this piece of magic called the readLine() command, which is a native function in Swift.

When the HackerRank system executes your code, it passes your code lines of input and this is a way of retrieving that input.

```
let line1 = readLine()
let line2 = readLine()
let line3 = readLine()
```

line1 is now given the value of the first line of input mentioned in the question (or delivered to your code by one of the test cases), with line2 being the second and so on.

Your code may work just great but may fail on a bunch of other test cases. These test cases don't send your code the same number of lines of input. Here's food for thought:

```
var string = ""

while let thing = readLine() {
string += thing + " "
}

print(string)
```

Now the string variable contains all the input there was to receive (as a String, in this case).

Hope that helps someone

:)

Answer (score 26):

Definitely you shouldn't do this:

```
while let readString = readLine() {
    s += readString
}
```

This because Swift will expect an input string (from readLine) forever and will never terminate, causing your application die by timeout.

Instead you should think in a for loop assuming you know how many lines you need to read, which is usually this way in HackerRank ;)

Try something like this:

```
let n = Int(readLine()!)! // Number of test cases
for _ in 1 ... n { // Loop from 1 to n
    let line = readLine()! // Read a single line
    // do something with input
}
```

If you know that each line is an integer, you can use this:

```
let line = Int(readLine()!)!
```

Or if you know each line is an array of integers, use this:

```
let line = readLine()!.characters.split(" ").map{ Int(String($0))! }
```

Or if each line is an array of strings:

```
let line = readLine()!.characters.split(" ").map{ String($0) }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Vlad, thanks for your suggestions! I wrote the 'while' code because the number of lines of input this particular challenge gave was different and increasingly larger for each successive test case. The while strategy worked and didn't cause any timeout. So it's safe to use. Your method makes more sense though, as I just realized that a value in the first line of input represented the total number of lines to follow. Guess I overlooked that haha. I was wondering what to do with that piece of info lol.

Comment: Apparently it works some what like a stack, and calling readLine() will retrieve one line from this stack and when the stack is empty (no more input), the readLine() results as nil, which breaks the while loop.

Comment: Great explanation for reading standard input in Swift! One question how would I fetch the index of the first element in a line, from 
let line = readLine()!.characters.split(" ").map{ Int(String($0))! } ?

Comment: @DaisyR. I'm not sure what you mean. Can you give an example?

Comment: Sorry I meant getting the index of an element in the line so line.indexOf() or line[0]. I figured it out

Comment: @DaisyR. The line is converted to an array so you can access any index you want or even loop through it :)

Comment: I did an experiment to find out my failing test cases in Swift but was passed smoothly in other language and found that Swift input is slow and causes my test to fail. Is there any way to improve Swift input time?

Answer (score 7):

For new version, to get an array of numbers separated by space

```
let numbers = readLine()!.components(separatedBy: [" "]).map { Int($0)! }
```

Comment: Fixing above statement: let numbers = readLine()!.components(separatedBy: " ").map { Int($0)! }

Answer (score 5):

#### Using `readLine()` and `AnyGenerator` to construct a `String` array of the std input lines

[`readLine()`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/func/readLine/) will read from standard input line-by-line until EOF is hit, whereafter it returns `nil`.

> Returns `Character`s read from standard input through the end of the
>   current line or until EOF is reached, *or `nil` if EOF has already been
>   reached*.

This is quite neat, as it makes `readLine()` a perfect candidate for generating a sequence using the [`AnyGenerator`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/AnyGenerator/) initializer `init(body:)` which recursively (as `next()`) invokes `body`, terminating in case `body` equals `nil`.

> **`AnyGenerator`**
>
> ```
> init(body: () -> Element?)
> ```
>
> Create a `GeneratorType` instance whose `next` method invokes `body`
>   and returns the result.

With this, there's no need to actually supply the amount of lines we expect from standard input, and hence, we can catch all input from standard input e.g. into a `String` array, where each element corresponds to an input line:

```
let allLines = AnyGenerator { readLine() }.map{ $0 }
    // type: Array<String>
```

After which we can work with the `String` array to apply whatever operations needed to solve a given task (/HackerRank task).

```
// example standard input
4 3
<tag1 value = "HelloWorld">
<tag2 name = "Name1">
</tag2>
</tag1>
tag1.tag2~name
tag1~name
tag1~value

/* resulting allLines array:
   ["4 3", "<tag1 value = \"HelloWorld\">", 
    "<tag2 name = \"Name1\">", 
    "</tag2>", 
    "</tag1>", 
    "tag1.tag2~name", 
    "tag1~name", 
    "tag1~value"] */
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently discovered a neat trick to get a certain amount of lines. I'm gonna assume the first line gives you the amount of lines you get:

```
guard let count = readLine().flatMap({ Int($0) }) else { fatalError("No count") }

let lines = AnyGenerator{ readLine() }.prefix(count)

for line in lines {

}
```

Comment: I am wondering, that you are creating an Array of String, which gives you the opportunity to work on the lines in a pure functional side-effect-free way (e.g. using 'map') and then you use a for-loop again, which throws you back into mutating data.

Comment: AnyGenerator had changed to AnyIterator.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use this form.

```
if let line = readLine(), let cnt = Int(line) {
    for _ in 1...cnt {
        if let line = readLine() {
            // your code for a line
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the [answer from dfrib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39021377/1493373), for Swift 3+, *AnyIterator* can be used instead of AnyGenerator, in the same way:

```swift
let allLines = AnyIterator { readLine() }.map{ $0 }
    // type: Array<String>
```