# Can swift while loops use functions as parameters?

Tags: ios, swift, while-loop

I'm working on a practice challenge question that uses a online compiler.  I've written the code below and it works in Xcode but the online compiler is saying I have it wrong.

Here is my code which I know is right and works in Xcode:

```
func squareThatNumber(input: Int) -> Int{
            let x: Int = input * input
            return x
        }

        print(squareThatNumber(input: 5))
```

Maybe I'm not understanding the question because the online compiler is starting off with this code which I've never seen a while loop written this way:

```
import Foundation

while let line: String = readLine() {
    print(line)
}
```

Can someone explain what the above code is doing because it compiles in the online compiler but I've never seen a while loop use a function.  Any direction or resource explaining this in detail is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should avoid unnecessary type annotation, such as `: Int` on `x`, and `: String` on line. Also, I would remove the temporary variable `x` and just use `return input * input`. There would be a point to extracting that to its own variable if it had a meaningful variable name, but `x` is not such a name

Comment: @EricAya The compiler doesn't error out.  It seems like the the compiler is running the while loop function so it's asking me to interject my function into the while loop somehow so that the squared integers are printed inside the while loop.

Comment: Lookup "optional  binding" in the Swift Reference book.

Comment: Hey @Alexander and I think I agree.  I figured I was being fancy by declaring the type.  Why wouldn't you recommend it this way?

Comment: @user6510422 Because it adds no meaningful information. It's just unnecessary visual clutter. There are times when it's useful to add an explicit annotation when dealing with complex expressions, even if it's not strictly necessary, in order to improve the readability of the code. This is not such a case.

Comment: To see the documentation for `readLine`, command-click on it in Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code calls `readLine()` at the start of every iteration. The result of that function is a `String?` (a.k.a. `Optional<String>`). If there is really a `String` there, it'll be bound to the variable `line`, and the block will be called once. This process is repeated until the binding isn't possible, that is, until `readLine()` returns `nil`.

Comment: how is it an optional string l if it doesn't have a '?' appended to the type?

Comment: @user6510422 What do you mean? [`readLine()` returns `String?`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1641199-readline)

Comment: @user6510422: It is called "optional binding". It is a key concept of Swift. You should read about it.

Comment: @user6510422 What Martin said ^ It's a pretty integral part of the language

Answer (score 0):

@Alexander answer provides the right information to understand what is happening.  After searching SO, this challenge is similar to what is on HackerRank and answered in this [SO question as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050506/how-to-get-multiple-lines-of-stdin-swift-hackerrank)

The code that worked in this online compiler is the following which Alexander pointed out how it works:

```
import Foundation

func squareThatNumber(input: Int) -> Int{
            let x = input * input
            return x
        }

while let line: String = readLine() {

    print(squareThatNumber(Int(line)!))

}
```